# Checking Mockery arguments using Mockery::contains( )

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, phpunit, mockery

I am using Mockery to test a class that creates calendar events. It passes timestamps of the start and end date to my EventRepository's `create()` method. There is other data included as arguments, but I only care that the timestamps are correct for this test.

This code works fine for testing the creation of **one** event:

```
$this->repo->shouldReceive('create')->once()
           ->with(Mockery::contains(1466460000, 1466467200));
```

However when I extend the Mock to the `create()` method being called **twice**, it fails.

```
$this->repo->shouldReceive('create')->twice()
           ->with(Mockery::contains(1466460000, 1466467200),
                 Mockery::contains(1466632800, 1466640000));
```

Doesn't Mockery use the syntax `->with(args1, args2)` for specifying the arguments for multiple calls to the same function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax with the multiple arguments are used when the method under test has multiple arguments.

For your use case you'll need to do as follows:

```
$this->repo->shouldReceive('create')->once()
          ->with(Mockery::contains(1466460000, 1466467200));
$this->repo->shouldReceive('create')->once()
          ->with(Mockery::contains(1466632800, 1466640000));
```